# Помогите выравнять рекапчу

Tags: css, recaptcha

Сам phpшник, попросили капчу встроить. Встроил, но она уезжает.
Задача: не вносить изменения в код, а сделать все через CSS.
Сайт https://okna-moskvi.ru/  "Обратный звонок".
Также и внизу рекапча на главной сдвинута.
Чего то я уже сижу битый час и не знаю к чему привязаться, чтобы и в мобильной было все хорошо.
Буду благодарен за наводку. Не знаю как иначе показать, поэтому показываю сайт.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ты никак не сделаешь без вмешательства в DOM дерево.
Либо через JS поменяй DOM, либо через HTML.
В идеале помести это все счастье в один блок родительский блок. 
Ты никак не отцентрируешь через css.
Максимум - с помощью JS.
```

```css
    .d-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    .d-flex div{
    margin: 10px 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="d-flex">
    <div>
    <input>
    </div>
    <div>
    ТУТ БУДЕТ ТВОЯ КАПЧА
    </div>
```

```
Если главное сделать, добавь такие стили блоку с капчей.
.simplecallback div#captcha {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
}
```